# How to send ISO message 8583 to host server in PHP or Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, iso8583

Anyone can share me a sample code to send iso message 8583 via  tcp/ip to host server and do we have simulator to track what message i sent to host in PHP or Laravel.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the transport level of ISO 8583. But there is [a library](https://packagist.org/packages/miome/iso8583) that pack / unpack ISO 8583 message. Have you try it?

Comment: @KoalaYeung i already try that package but i don't know how to send to host server

Comment: As far as I can tell, ISO 8583 only defines the packing / unpacking of message. It has nothing to say about sending and receiving. That part would probably be vendor specific. Does your vendor provide and documentation about this?

Comment: If your vendor only require a simple TCP connection (or with TLS), just take a look at [fsockopen()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fsockopen.php). Reading from / writing to TCP port with the function should be easy.

Comment: @KoalaYeung i read that so fsocketopen can send iso message by packing right?

Comment: You'd better read your vendor documentation first. As I said before, ISO 8583 never defined how you shousld send the message. fsocketopen is how you usually send anything through raw TCP connection.

Answer (score 1):

Typically connections to bank hosts using ISO 8583 are persistent asynchronous connections with request and responses interleaved.  Most of the time these days, as noted in one of the comments they're simple TCP/IP.  Typically the bank host will have a preferred header which specifies the length of the data that follows.  I've seen various flavors with either one, two or four bytes.  Also, the length may or may not include the length bytes themselves.

So, I would imagine once you nail down the specifics for your host's requirements it should be a simple matter to establish a connection.

Managing the requests and responses can be a challenge, however, as the traffic is asynchronous.  This means you may send multiple requests before the response to the first one has arrived.  You'll need to maintain some sort of transaction context, and match the responses to the requests.  You will need to determine what your matching criteria will need to be.  It will need to be data elements that are common to both request and response messages.  Occasionally, the host message format will define a request field that will be guaranteed to be echoed back in the response.  Using such fields for matching is OK, I wouldn't recommend using it for other purposes.  In my experience (25+ years) whenever I've resorted to using it for other reasons it's always come back to bite me.